# Django admin page structure for multiple organizations

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm currently building an Django application which could be used by several different organizations, each would have their own group of users. The goal is that staff from one organization can only see/edit model instances added by its own staff in the admin page. Each organization will also have an admin who can add revoke the rights of a staff member in their organization.

So how should I go about with this and how do I custom my admin page? Do I need to create custom model for User./Organization or just django group would do?

Comment: Take a look to customization mechanizm: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite

Comment: I've checked out the customization mechanism, but it only shows how you can register custom model and field in the admin site, and not how to set Organization model.

Comment: What about idea to create different urls for multiple organization. Each url will route to yourself customized admin site